# Integrating random variables correctly

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $X,Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two random variables on a probability space $(\Omega , \Sigma, P)$

The expectation value of $f(X,Y)$ is then given by

$\int_{\Omega} f(X( \omega) , Y(\omega) ) dP(\omega).$

Now is this the same as

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ or the same as
$\int_{(X,Y)(\Omega)} f(x,y) dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$
here $dP_{(X,Y)}$ denotes the push-forward measure. $(X,Y)(\Omega):=\{(X(\omega),Y(\omega)); \omega \in \Omega\}.$

Comment: The push-forward is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\Omega$.

Comment: @Both $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(X,Y)(\Omega)$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ not $\Omega$, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your definition closely enough. Anyway, both of  your integrals are equal since $(X,Y)(\Omega)$ has $P_{(X,Y)}$-measure equal to 1.

Comment: ah, so the support of the measure gives us in this case, that the expressions are equal, although in general only $(X,Y)(\Omega)$ would be correct?

Comment: Er, no, the point is that the support of the measure is $(X,Y)(\Omega)$, so if you integrate over $\mathbb{R}^2$, everything else just gives zero.